# how can i post large size image with hyperlink to Facebook from iPhone programmatically

Tags: iphone, facebook

[image]

hi

i need to post large size image with hyperlink from iPhone to Facebook wall programmatically.here i used Facebook SDKs to post image and i used "me/photos". this is my code to post image.

```
- FbGraphFile *graph_file = [[FbGraphFile alloc]
   initWithImage:myImage];
   [variables setObject:graph_file forKey:@"file"];
          NSString *strMovie=[dicDetails objectForKey:JSON_MOVIENAME];
          NSString *strUsername=[[[DTO_Handler start]DTO_dicLogin]objectForKey:JSON_FNAME];
          NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.moviemouse.com/"];
          NSString *strMessage=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@ %@",strUsername,@"          likes the movie '",strMovie,@"' via
   MovieMouse.",url];
          [variables setObject:strMessage forKey:@"message"];
          FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"me/photos" withPostVars:variables];
```

i can post image in Facebook wall.but i can't link. i need exactly as same like image given below. if i click "instagram" it will redirect to some url.how can i post like this.

Waiting for a solution. please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can only put the HTTP URL you want to “link” to into the `message` parameter, as pure text.

Making it a clickable link is what Facebook will do on their own when showing the message on the user’s wall.

Should work exactly the same way, as if the user was uploading the image directly on facebook.com, and typing the message text containing an URL.